# Find all Combinations of a sorted sequence of characters

Tags: c#, combinations

For the following characters `a,b,c,d` I want to find the following combinations.

The sequence is always sorted. I wonder how I should approach in finding the combinations?

```
a
b
c
d

ab
ac
ad

bc
bd

cd

abc
abd
acd

bcd

abcd
```

Comment: Those aren't permutations, they're combinations.

Comment: What you want are not the **permutations** but the **subsets**. You can generate them using a DFS-like recursive function. You can check [this link](http://compprog.wordpress.com/2007/10/10/generating-subsets/) for an explanation on how to do that.

Comment: You'll need to define a mximum length for you sequence, or you'll find the program runs for a while :)

Comment: thanks for clearing out the concept

Comment: If the order matters, that is abcd is to be considered different from acbd, then thats permutation. What he needs is a permutation of 1,2,3 and 4 characters. Calling it a combination is wrong.

Comment: So the total number of possibilities is 4p1+4p2+4p3+4p4=64

Comment: http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is every single Combination.  Normally when getting combinations you get all combinations of a particular size, n.  We'll start out by creating that method to get the combinations of size n from a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(
      this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();


    int count = 1;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        foreach (var innerSequence in source.Skip(count).Combinations(n - 1))
        {
            yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(innerSequence);
        }
        count++;
    }
}
```

Once you have that it's a simple matter of getting the combinations of n for all n from 1 to the size of the sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> output = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        output = output.Concat(source.Combinations(i));
    }
    return output;
}
```

Some sample code that uses it:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

foreach (var sequence in list.AllCombinations())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", sequence));
}
```

It's worth noting that this operation is extraordinarily expensive for all but the tiniest input sequences.  It's not exactly the most efficient around, but even if you do eek out every last bit of performance you won't be able to compute the combinations of sequences of more than 15-20, depending on how long you're willing to wait and how good your computer is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Combinatorics](http://nuget.org/packages/Combinatorics) library to calculate them for you ([documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G)), but as Servy said, length of the data is a major factor in how long it will take.

Answer (score 0):

They're not truly subsets because there's nothing to stop your input sequence from containing duplicates, but the following extension method should work in the general case:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Subsets<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    List<T[]> yielded = new List<T[]> { new T[0] };
    foreach(T t in source)
    {
        List<T[]> newlyYielded = new List<T[]>();
        foreach(var y in yielded)
        {
            var newSubset = y.Concat(new[] {t}).ToArray();
            newlyYielded.Add(newSubset);
            yield return newSubset;
        }
        yielded.AddRange(newlyYielded);
    }
}
```

Basically starting with an empty sequence, it adds the empty sequence with the first item appended. Then for each of those two sequences, it adds that sequence with the next item appended. Then for each of those four sequences...

This has to keep a copy of each sequence generated, so will use a lot of memory.

To get strings out of string, you can call this as

```
"abcd".Subsets().Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()))
```

If you're not going to have many characters, you could take advantage of the fact that you can calculate the nth subset directly:

```
public static int SubsetCount(this string s)
{
    return 2 << s.Length;
}
public static string NthSubset(this string s, int n)
{
    var b = New StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if ((n&1)==1) b.Append(s[i]);
        i++;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return b.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a class to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient, which is the type of problem that your problem falls under.  I have not looked at the Cominatorics library suggested by @Bobson, but I believe my class is probably much faster and more efficient.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper index of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle.  My paper talks about this.  I believe I am the first to discover and publish this technique, but I could be wrong.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.  I believe it might be faster than the link you have found.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to perform the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

The solution to your problem involves generating the K-indexes for each N choose K case.  So in your example above where there are 4 possibilities for N (A, B, C, D) the code (in C#) would look something like this:

```
int TotalNumberOfValuesInSet = 4;
int N = TotalNumberOfValuesInSet;
// Loop thru all the possible groups of combinations.
for (int K = N - 1; K < N; K++)
{
   // Create the bin coeff object required to get all
   // the combos for this N choose K combination.
   BinCoeff<int> BC = new BinCoeff<int>(N, K, false);
   int NumCombos = BinCoeff<int>.GetBinCoeff(N, K);
   int[] KIndexes = new int[K];
   // Loop thru all the combinations for this N choose K case.
   for (int Combo = 0; Combo < NumCombos; Combo++)
   {
      // Get the k-indexes for this combination, which in this case
      // are the indexes to each letter in the set starting with index zero.
      BC.GetKIndexes(Loop, KIndexes);
      // Do whatever processing that needs to be done with the indicies in KIndexes.
      ...
   }
   // Handle the final combination which in this case is ABCD since since K < N.
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of [servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) above is quite elegant, but it doesn't produce those combinations that have the same length as the source.

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++) should be
for (int i = 0; i <= source.Count; i++).
```

Below is the vb.net variant, which can't use yield.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Combinations(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), n As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
    Dim lstResults As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of T))

    If n = 0 Then
        lstResults.Add(Enumerable.Empty(Of T))
    Else
        Dim count As Integer = 1


        For Each item As T In source
            For Each innerSequence In source.Skip(count).Combinations(n - 1)
                lstResults.Add(New T() {item}.Concat(innerSequence))
            Next
            count += 1
        Next
    End If

    Return lstResults

End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function AllCombinations(Of T)(source As IList(Of T)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T))
    Dim output As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of T)) = Enumerable.Empty(Of IEnumerable(Of T))()

    For i As Integer = 0 To source.Count
        output = output.Concat(source.Combinations(i))
    Next
    Return output

End Function
```